# Stack Overflow got demoted in the footer, no longer listed first

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, footer

I just noticed this on the footers:

[image: hyperventilating about where footer links are listed]

Stack Overflow is gone!

Actually, it's still there. It's just the **third from the bottom of the list**!

Isn't Stack Overflow the big site around here, the one that started everything, that **deserves the first spot**?

Comment: They got alphabetized. :o Well, at least the Technology category did (mostly). IT Security kind of looks out of place when you order it by the "Security" part rather than the "IT" part.

Comment: Meh.  It's just an Ek.

Comment: They're sorting by the URL rather than the title, which explains why the other categories look mis-organized. For example, Science is "cstheory" - "math" - "mathoverflow" - "physics" - "stats"

Comment: Sorting by URL explains some things, but not Travel being in front of Bicycles. ... Oh, I think I get it. Travel is Culture, Bicycles are Recreation.

Comment: +1 for "high level of eekiness"

Comment: I'm fine with wherever SO is placed on the footer. But a) I doubt many people find SO via the footer; b) I doubt people see a site's position in the footer as a indicator of its importance.

Comment: @doubleDown I use it often as a quick shortcut.

Comment: Ok that sounds like a legit reason for eeking. FWIW, if you click "Stack Exchange" on the left of header -> "all sites", SO would be on first spot if your SO account has higher rep than your other SE accounts.

Comment: @double Yes, but that's two clicks. I'm lazy!

Comment: @random You removed the indication of the eeekiness!

Comment: Are you saying this is only worth bringing up, and leaving open, if you include "eeeeek" in the post?

Comment: @random No, but you are downplaying the eeekiness. It's not worth keeping open either way, but it's still eeeky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow is back at the top, where it belongs.

We had a recent performance related change in the code path that picked up data for the footer - and it had a bug, causing the primary sort order of the sites in a category to no longer work (they all had the same value for it), causing the issue.

For reference - in the footer, within a category, the sites are ordered by their launch dates.